# Beef installation problem in Windows 10 - 64 bit

Tags: web-application, windows, xss, ruby

I am trying to install Beef in a WIndows 10 - 64 bit PC.
I followed the instructions provided in the following link:

https://github.com/beefproject/beef/blob/master/INSTALL.txt

But I keep getting this error:

> An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.11.4), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.4'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

I drilled down a bit & found that the installed version of therubyracer is **0.11.0beta1 x86-mingw32** whereas the installer is searching for version  **0.11.4**

In the link provided above, the following lines are mentioned in line 38:

***Finally, edit beef's gem lock file by replacing the required ruby racer version with the version downloaded from the link above.***

But when I do that I get this error:

> Your lockfile is unreadable. Run `rm Gemfile.lock` and then `bundle
>   install` to generate a new lockfile.

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: What are the rights on the Gemfile.lock?

Comment: The current user has full access with full control enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that all versions coincide E.G. If you are using a 64-bit version of Ruby make sure you use the appropriate 0.11.0beta1 x64-mingw and not the 0.11.0beta1 x86-mingw32 as you mentioned above.

Cheers!